# Initial Odoo 16 Custom Module Not Installing

Tags: python-3.x, module, odoo-16

I'm new to development of Odoo modules and I'm going through the Training module, but I'm trying to do so with something that is going to be functional for my company. I'm just trying to test that the module is creating the model properly, creating the appropriate database table fields. Unfortunately nothing is being created and it doesn't look like the module is being loaded correctly.

The module files are stored in addons\baz_test

**manifest**.py and models\baz_test.py included (some text changes have been made to name,descroption and author for the manifest, and _name and _description changed in baz_test.py

**manifest**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': 'Baz Test',
    'version': '1.0',
    'description': 'A module to store data for a module test made by baz. Desc matches OG desc length',
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'depends':["base"],
    'author': 'Baz' ,
    'category': 'Customizations',
    "license" : "LGPL-3"
}
```

models\baz_test.py

```
from odoo import models, api, fields

class WMQuotesDashboard(models.Model):
    _name = "baz.test"
    _description = "Baz Test"
    _order = "quote_date"
    _rec_name = 'quote_date'
    quote_date = fields.Date(string='Quotation Date', required=True)
    user_id = fields.Many2one("res.users", string="User", required=True)
    amount_total = fields.Monetary(currency_field='currency_id', required=True, string="Total Quotes")
    currency_id = fields.Many2one("res.currency", string="Currency")
```

when running Odoo with -u baz_test this is the following output...

```
2023-11-02 22:42:19,248 12264 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.update_list on [] to user __system__ #1 via n/a
2023-11-02 22:42:20,533 12264 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.button_upgrade on ['Baz Test'] to user __system__ #1 via n/a
2023-11-02 22:42:20,533 12264 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.update_list on ['Baz Test'] to user __system__ #1 via n/a
2023-11-02 22:42:20,995 12264 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.button_install on [] to user __system__ #1 via n/a
2023-11-02 23:07:55,425 25360 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: loading 53 modules...
2023-11-02 23:07:55,430 25360 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: Loading module baz_test (4/53)
2023-11-02 23:07:55,516 25360 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: Module baz_test loaded in 0.09s, 14 queries (+14 other)
2023-11-02 23:07:56,097 25360 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: 53 modules loaded in 0.67s, 14 queries (+14 extra)
```

I was expecting the module to load and for the PostGreSQL DB to update with a new table and associated fields.

I've tried changing the manifest, ensuring that the model name is the same as the folder name, and using the folder name as the name for the -u argument and everything seems in order. So I don't know why the module isn't being installed and the tables/columns added.

I'm just trying to get the model before even attempting getting the views sorted. I've checked and the model is installed

EDIT: Add some changes resolving some code issues that I've solved but still haven't added the model. I also have verified that the model is up to date and installed. (ir_module_module) shows 'Baz Test' is installed but there's no indications of data available.

Answer (score 1):

The *-u* parameter does not install an uninstalled module it is for updating an already installed module.

You need to use the *-i* parameter. Keep in mind that both of these parameter require you to specify the exact database you want the module installed/updated on via the *-d* parameter. It would also help if you posted the full command you use to run Odoo because maybe something else is also wrong.

If you still can't manage to install it via parameters you can always just go into Odoo and install the module from the Apps menu which will then create your table in the database.

Source: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/cli.html#running-the-server

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ir.model table for your model. Either in the PostgreSQL database or simply in the Odoo user interface. You will find a list of models under Settings->Technical->Models.

The "Technical" menu item is only visible with debug mode enabled, there is a Chrome extension called "Odoo Debug" that does this for you, otherwise, you can also find the debug mode in Settings->General Settings->Activate the developer mode.